Apache Pulsar Broker initialization error due to initContainer test failure
I'm deploying Apache Pulsar via Helm chart, v3.8.0 (latest at this time).
The K8s cluster is on EKS, deployment via ArgoCD.
It fails to initialize the Broker (and Proxy, which depend on Broker).
The failure stems from the initContainer that checks that ZooKeeper is deployed and setup with an entry for the cluster.
Here's the initContainer that keeps failing (i.e. in the log I get the echoed message repeated pulsar cluster pulsar-cluster-dev isn't initialized yet ... check in 3 seconds ...):
 initContainers:
  - args:
    - |2-

      export BOOKIE_MEM="-Xmx128M"; until timeout 15 bin/pulsar zookeeper-shell -server pulsar-zookeeper:2181 get /admin/clusters/pulsar-cluster-dev; do
        echo "pulsar cluster pulsar-cluster-dev isn't initialized yet ... check in 3 seconds ..." && sleep 3;
      done;
    command:
    - timeout
    - "600"
    - sh
    - -c
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar-all:4.0.1
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: wait-zookeeper-ready
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 256Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-csbzb
      readOnly: true

I am able to connect to ZooKeeper when I port-forward it locally, and its up and running, and the entry at /admin/clusters/pulsar-cluster-dev is correctly populated, with:
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] get /admin/clusters/pulsar-cluster-dev
{"brokerClientTlsKeyStoreType":"JKS","brokerClientSslFactoryPlugin":"org.apache.pulsar.common.util.DefaultPulsarSslFactory","brokerClientTlsEnabledWithKeyStore":false,"brokerClientTlsTrustStoreType":"JKS","brokerServiceUrlTls":"pulsar+ssl://pulsar-broker.dev.svc.cluster.local:6651/","brokerClientTlsEnabled":false,"tlsAllowInsecureConnection":false,"serviceUrl":"http://pulsar-broker.dev.svc.cluster.local:8080/","serviceUrlTls":"https://pulsar-broker.dev.svc.cluster.local:8443/","brokerServiceUrl":"pulsar://pulsar-broker.dev.svc.cluster.local:6650/"}

The values.yaml and whole Argo Application (values object embedded; StorageClass ebs-sc is independently correctly deployed on the cluster, PVCs created as expected):
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: pulsar
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: dev  # Namespace where Pulsar will be deployed
    name: dev2  # Target cluster
  source:
    repoURL: https://pulsar.apache.org/charts  # URL to the Pulsar Helm chart repository
    chart: pulsar  # Name of the Helm chart
    targetRevision: 3.8.0  # Specify the Helm chart version
    helm:
      valuesObject:

        ## Set to true on install
        initialize: true
        ## Set useReleaseStatus to false if you're deploying this chart using a system that doesn't track .Release.IsInstall or .Release.IsUpgrade (like argocd)
        useReleaseStatus: false
        ## Set cluster name
        clusterName: pulsar-cluster-dev

        zookeeper:
          replicaCount: 1
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 300Mi
              cpu: 0.3
          configData:
            PULSAR_MEM: "-Xms300m -Xmx300m -Djute.maxbuffer=10485760 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError"
          volumes:
            data:
              local_storage: false
              storageClassName: ebs-sc

        bookkeeper:
          replicaCount: 1
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: 0.3
          configData:
            BOOKIE_MEM: "-Xms312m -Xmx312m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError"
          volumes:
            common:
              local_storage: false
              storageClassName: ebs-sc

            journal:
              local_storage: false
              storageClassName: ebs-sc

            ledgers:
              local_storage: false
              storageClassName: ebs-sc

        broker:
          component: broker
          replicaCount: 1
          ledger:
            defaultEnsembleSize: 1
            defaultAckQuorum: 1
            defaultWriteQuorum: 1
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 600Mi
              cpu: 0.3
          configData:
            PULSAR_MEM: "-Xms400m -Xmx400m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError"

        autoRecovery:
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 300Mi
              cpu: 0.3

        function:
          replicaCount: 1
          functionReplicaCount: 1
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: 0.3
          configData:
            PULSAR_MEM: "-Xms312m -Xmx312m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError"

        proxy:
          replicaCount: 1
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: 0.3
          wsResources:
            requests:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: 0.3
          configData:
            PULSAR_MEM: "-Xms400m -Xmx400m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=112m"
          autoPortAssign:
            enablePlainTextWithTLS: true
          service:
            autoPortAssign:
              enabled: true

        grafanaDashboards:
          enabled: false

        pulsarAdminConsole:
          replicaCount: 1

        kube-prometheus-stack:
          enabled: false

  project: default  # ArgoCD project (default unless configured otherwise)
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true  # Automatically delete resources no longer defined in the chart
      selfHeal: true  # Automatically correct drifted resources
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true


Any help would be much appreciated

Issue resolved
Root cause - the broker service's initContainer to test zookeeper connectivity together with the broker itself were too resource heavy for the node types in the node group (t3.small, 2gb RAM).
Created a new nodegroup, with t3.medium nodes, 4gb RAM, and migrated the cluster to use that instead.
